# Powershell script and pipeline

Tags: powershell

I want to know if this command can be written without the pipelines(vertical lines)?

```
$u=gwmi Win32_Volume|?{$_.Label -eq'_'}|select name;cd $u.name;.\d.cmd
```

Comment: Your keyboard doesn't have the pipe symbol?  (This post is on Technet too.)   That's very limiting.  There's always copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

So to start you should always try to move the filters left, so if the cmdlet in question has a filtering capability try to use it.  In this case it will spare you the | Where-Object.

```
$Vols = gwmi -Query "SELECT Name FROM Win32_Volume WHERE Label = '_'"
```

At this point I think you're in good shape, but the subsequent commands:

```
cd $Vols.name
.\d.cmd
```

These may not work if $Vols returns multiple objects.

I don't know what the real intent is, but strictly speaking you can still avoid the pipeline with something like:

```
ForEach($Vol in $Vols){ 
    cd $Vol.name
    .\d.cmd
}
```

That's why I changed $u to $Vols...

If you only wanted to work with the name property you can focus on is with automatic variable unrolling like:

```
$Vols = (gwmi -Query "SELECT Name FROM Win32_Volume WHERE Label ='_'" ).Name

ForEach($Vol in $Vols){ 
    cd $Vol
    .\d.cmd
}
```

Let me know what you think we can work further on it.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` block can be replaced by a WMI filter and the `select` statement can be replaced with the member reference (`.`) operator.

Finally, you can join the result of that operation directly to the file name and skip `cd`:

```bsh
& (Join-Path (gwmi Win32_Volume -Filter "Label = '_'").Name 'd.cmd')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$u=gwmi Win32_Volume|?{$_.Label -eq '_'}|select name
```

and

```
$u = foreach ( $a in (gwmi Win32_Volume) ) { if ($a.Label -eq '_') { [PSCustomObject]@{Name = $a.Name}} }
```

Above commands are equivalent however both could result to one of the following:

- a `PSCustomObject` (then `$u.Name` gives a string), or
- an array (then `$u.Name` gives an array as well so that `cd $u.Name` would fail), or
- `$null` value (then `$u.Name` throws an error and `cd $u.Name` would fail as well).